# UICollectionView display

Tags: iphone, uiview

Before scrolling

[image: Before scrolling]

After scrolling

[image: After scrolling]

Why is this happening?

Here's the code to add header.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (reusableview==nil) {
        reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    }

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recipe Group #%i", indexPath.section];
    [reusableview addSubview:label];

    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.section);
    return reusableview;
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: may be your label size problem check it.

Comment: Create my label UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        
        if (reusableview==nil) {
            reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        }
        
        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recipe Group #%i", indexPath.section];
        [reusableview addSubview:label];

Comment: Please take the time to edit your question and add the code properly formatted (For help : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Just an hint : it clearly looks like you are overlapping text fields (the first one looks like a "4" overlapped on a "1", the second one like a "3" on a "2").

My guess is you are somewhere in your code a place when you think you are updating a view, whereas you are actually adding a new one to the already existing.

From your (unformatted and out of context) code, it seems you are using `[reusableview addSubview:label];`. I would look into that bearing my previous remark in mind.